# EXT JS code to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I have used Ext JS in my existing web application.
Currently I want to move from Ext JS to jQuery.

Are there any standard steps for moving Ext JS code to jQuery ?

Please provide your suggestions!!

Thanks

Pravin

Comment: Can you tell us why did you decide to move to jQuery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ExtJS is high-level library (rich UI, widgets, etc.) while jQuery is not. Unless you mean [Ext Core](http://www.sencha.com/products/extcore/) I highly doubt you can transition easily and to your benefit.

In short: don't do it.

Comment: I agree, what is the OP using in extjs (and what version). I cannot imagine going back to jquery trees, grids, and loosing data direct. But if I was just using what jqueryui has to offer and maybe a few plugins, well I wouldn't have chosen extjs, but the work wouldnt be hard to recode.

Answer (score 0):

1. Figure out what widgets from Ext you need to keep
2. Google for jQuery plugins that will do the same thing
3. Start coding

Comment: An obvious answer to an obvious question worth a downvote? Nice!